flutter failed build apk
com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key upload from store "/Users/haryandb/upload-keystore.jks": Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available
╰─ flutter build apk
 Building with sound null safety 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.


A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key upload from store "/Users/haryandb/upload-keystore.jks": Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available


solve link
